# Exception isn't thrown when nil inserted in NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, nsdictionary, null

So I was working on pulling photos from user's Facebook album and for some reason NSDictionary doesn't throw an exception when nil is inserted.
I've tested it on a real device and on iOS simulator (both iOS 7).
Maybe debugger crashes, maybe it's Facebook SDK bug.
Anyway, I'm ready to listen to your opinion.

UPDATE: One more thing I forgot to mention. In debugger, after inserting nil object in dictionary, debugger itself continues program execution. And I'm not even pressing the buttong "Continue program execution".

Here's the snippet

```
- (void)downloadAlbumsWithCompletionBlock:(void (^)(NSArray *albums, NSError *error))completionBlock;
{
    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/albums"
                                 parameters:nil
                                 HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                          completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
    {
        if (error)
        {
            NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
            completionBlock(nil, error);
        }
        else
        {
            NSMutableArray *data = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
            NSMutableArray *albums = [NSMutableArray new];
            for (NSMutableDictionary *dict in data)
            {
                NSString *albumID = dict[@"id"];
                NSString *coverPhotoID = dict[@"cover_photo"];
                // coverPhotoID gets nil and then successfully gets put in NSDictionary
                // You can just write "NSString *coverPhotoID = nil;".
                NSString *description = dict[@"description"];
                NSString *name = dict[@"name"];
                NSDictionary *album = @{@"album_id": albumID,
                                      @"album_cover_photo_id": coverPhotoID,
                                      @"album_description": description,
                                      @"album_name": name };
                // Here an exception should be thrown but for some reason
                // we just quit out of the method. Result would be the same if we put
                // empty "return;" statement.
                // If we explicitly put nil, like 
                //   @"album_cover_photo_id": nil
                // we get compiler error.
                [albums addObject:album];
            }
            completionBlock(albums, nil);
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: Does the app still crash ?

Comment: You replaced `NSString *coverPhotoID = dict[@"cover_photo"];` with `NSString *coverPhotoID = nil;` and didn't crash?

Comment: To KIDdAe: no, app doesn't crash.

Comment: to rtiago42: yes, app didn't crash.

Comment: @eoLithic That's weird... I just wrote an app with the code `NSString *coverPhotoID = nil; NSDictionary *album = @{@"album_cover_photo_id": coverPhotoID};` and it crashes. Print the album dictionary to the log.

Comment: Well my thought was maybe the dictionary call to get the object from the value returns NSNull instead of nil but if you're flat setting the string to nil and it still works that's weird. It shouldn't work. Do you have a property of ivar with the same name as the NSString somewhere else in the code so it's using that instead and it's not actually adding the nil object?

Comment: @Cocoadelica I though NSNull as well. But it can't be an ivar because of scope priority.

Comment: To CocoaDelica: no, there is no ivar with the same name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wrote:

```
// Here an exception should be thrown but for some reason
// we just quit out of the method. Result would be the same if we put empty "return;" statement.
```

Most likely the exception is caught somewhere. Try putting a breakpoint on Objective-C exception throws (In Xcode, go to the Breakpoint tab, click + in the bottom left corner and select Add Exception Breakpoint. Make sure the parameters are set to Objective-C exception and break On Throw).

Comment: I did as you said. I've caught an exception, in debugger I wrote "po $eax" and got this: "*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[1]". So, yeah, turns out exception is thrown but how do I know who handles the exception? I've googled that question but found nothing.

Comment: I'd try to make continue step overs.

Comment: Well, nothing happens, program just waits for an event. I've made a little update to the post see it above.

Comment: I never had the need for it so I'm not sure how it works but in the Edit breakpoint options (left-click on the breakpoint in the list) you can set it to Break On Catch instead of On Throw, which should help you identify what catches the exception. Alternatively you can look at the stack of function calls (6th tab from the left) and unless you don't have the code for one of the functions you should be able to see what catches the exception. Maybe it's also possible that there is a global exception handler setup for your app? (See `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler`)

Comment: Now I have full answer: it was Facebook SDK's fault. Looks like it handles any exception that can happen inside the block. Well, what can I say: never trust 3-rd party components!

Answer (score 2):

You claim that

```
NSString *albumID = dict[@"id"];
NSString *coverPhotoID = nil;
NSString *description = dict[@"description"];
NSString *name = dict[@"name"];
NSDictionary *album = @{@"album_id": albumID,
                       @"album_cover_photo_id": coverPhotoID,
                       @"album_description": description,
                       @"album_name": name };
```

doesn't crash your app.

Honestly, I don't believe it. Either you're trolling or you're misinterpreting whats happening.

As the first line of your `for` cycle log the `dict` dictionary:

```
NSLog(@"dict var: %@", dict);
```

Does `dict` contains the key `album_cover_photo_id`?

If you get something like

```
"album_cover_photo_id" : null
```

then `NSString *coverPhotoID = dict[@"cover_photo"]` is assigning an NSNull instance to `coverPhotoID`. In that case the app doesn't crash because an NSNull instance is not `nil`.

```
NSString *coverPhotoID = nil;
```

is different then

```
NSString *coverPhotoID = [NSNull null];
```

It's very common for servers to return `null`s in JSON instead of omitting the key (server people are weird).

---

You can also log `album` after you create it

```
NSLog(@"album var: %@", album);
```

And if you are 100 % sure you're adding a `nil` to a dictionary, take it to the Apple developer forum. I bet they'd love to know about that bug.

I hope this helps you in some way.